# SQLite Auto Increment in java code not working properly

Tags: java, android, sqlite

my project group and I are running into an unusual error.
We are working on an app and use a local database that is created in the JAVA code, we are using Android Studio 2.1.1.1.

Sadly when we create an account it does not auto increment the USER_ID, in fact it always returns value "0" (without the quotation marks)
So is there an error in our Cursor? Is there an error in our creation of the SQLite Database? As far as I know an Integer Primary key is by default auto increment.

```
private static final String TABLE_CREATE_USER =
            "CREATE TABLE " + USER_TABLE + " (" +
                    USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                    USERNAME + " VARCHAR(200) NULL, " +
                    NAME + " VARCHAR(200) NULL, " +
                    EMAIL + " VARCHAR(200) NULL, " +
                    PHONENUMBER + " VARCHAR(200) NULL, " +
                    BUSINESS + " VARCHAR(200) NULL, " +
                    BIO + " VARCHAR(200) NULL, " +
                    HASSTARTUP + " VARCHAR(200) NULL, " +
                    PASSWORD + " VARCHAR(45) NULL " +
                    ")";
if(!database.isOpen())
            open();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        String query = "SELECT * FROM user ";
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);
        count = cursor.getCount();
        count++;

        values.put(DBOpenHelper.getUserId(), count);

        values.put(DBOpenHelper.getUsername(), user.get_AccountName());
        values.put(DBOpenHelper.getBio(), user.get_Bio());
        values.put(DBOpenHelper.getBusiness(), user.get_Businessname());
        values.put(DBOpenHelper.getEmail(), user.get_Email());
        values.put(DBOpenHelper.getPassword(), user.get_Password());
        values.put(DBOpenHelper.getPhonenumber(), user.get_Phonenumber());
        values.put(DBOpenHelper.getName(), user.get_Profilename());
        values.put(DBOpenHelper.getHasstartup(), user.get_hasStartup());

        database.insert(DBOpenHelper.getUserTable(), null, values);

        Log.i("Database", "CREATE SUCCES");

        if(database.isOpen())
            close();

    }
```

This is what we have right now:
here we create the table:

```
private static final String TABLE_CREATE_USER =
            "CREATE TABLE " + USER_TABLE + " (" +
                    USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                    USERNAME + " VARCHAR(200) NULL, " +
                    NAME + " VARCHAR(200) NULL, " +
                    EMAIL + " VARCHAR(200) NULL, " +
                    PHONENUMBER + " VARCHAR(200) NULL, " +
                    BUSINESS + " VARCHAR(200) NULL, " +
                    BIO + " VARCHAR(200) NULL, " +
                    BRANCHE + " VARCHAR(200) NULL, " +
                    HASSTARTUP + " VARCHAR(200) NULL, " +
                    PASSWORD + " VARCHAR(45) NULL " +
                    ")";
```

Putting Values into the user:

```
    public void createUser(User user){

            if(!database.isOpen())
                open();

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    //        String query = "SELECT * FROM user ";
    //        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);
    //        count = cursor.getCount();
    //        count++;

            values.put(DBOpenHelper.getUsername(), user.get_AccountName());
            values.put(DBOpenHelper.getBio(), user.get_Bio());
            values.put(DBOpenHelper.getBusiness(), user.get_Businessname());
            values.put(DBOpenHelper.getEmail(), user.get_Email());
            values.put(DBOpenHelper.getPassword(), user.get_Password());
            values.put(DBOpenHelper.getPhonenumber(), user.get_Phonenumber());
            values.put(DBOpenHelper.getName(), user.get_Profilename());
            values.put(DBOpenHelper.getHasstartup(), user.get_hasStartup());
            values.put(DBOpenHelper.getBranche(), user.get_branche());

            database.insert(DBOpenHelper.getUserTable(), null, values);

            Log.i("Database", "CREATE SUCCES");

            if(database.isOpen())
                close();

        }

Here we read/set the info from the create account fields:

public void onSignUpClick(View v)
    {
        if(v.getId() == R.id.BsignUpButton)
        {

            EditText email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.TFEmail);
            EditText uname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.TFUname);
            EditText companyName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.TFCompanyName);
            EditText pass1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.TFPass1);
            EditText pass2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.TFPass2);
            EditText branche = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.TFCompanyBranche);

            String emailstr = email.getText().toString();
            String unamestr = uname.getText().toString();
            String companyNamestr = companyName.getText().toString();
            String pass1str = pass1.getText().toString();
            String pass2str = pass2.getText().toString();
            String branchestr = branche.getText().toString();

            final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            progressDialog.setTitle("Creating account");
            progressDialog.setMessage("Creating... Plz wait...");
            progressDialog.show();

            Runnable progressRunnable = new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    progressDialog.cancel();
                }
            };

            Handler pdCanceller = new Handler();
            pdCanceller.postDelayed(progressRunnable, 3000);

            if(validatePassword(pass1str) && validateEmail(emailstr) && validatePassword(pass2str)){

                user.set_AccountName(unamestr);
                user.set_Profilename(" ");
                user.set_Businessname(companyNamestr);
                user.set_branche(branchestr);
                user.set_Password(pass1str);
                user.set_Email(emailstr);
                user.set_Bio(" ");
                user.set_Phonenumber(" ");
                user.set_hasStartup("yes");

                userDao.createUser(user);

                users = userDao.getUsers();

                Toast pass = Toast.makeText(this, "Account has been created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                pass.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.CENTER, 0, 10);
                pass.show();

                for (User u : users) {
                    String text = u.get_AccountName() + " " + u.get_id() + " " + u.get_branche();
                    Log.i("Database", text);
                }

//                logUserIn();
                Intent i = new Intent(this, Login.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }

            if(!pass1str.equals(pass2str))
            {
                pass2.setError("Passwords don't match");
                pass2.requestFocus();
            }

            if(emailstr.length() == 0 || unamestr.length() == 0 || pass1str.length() == 0 || pass2str.length() == 0 || companyNamestr.length() == 0 ){
                //popup msg
                Toast pass = Toast.makeText(SignUpBusiness.this, "Please fill in all the fields ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                pass.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.CENTER, 0, 10);
                pass.show();
            }

            if(!validateEmail(emailstr)) {
                email.setError("Invalid Email");
                email.requestFocus();
            }
            if (!validatePassword(pass1str)) {
                pass1.setError("Invalid Password, use 10 or more characters");
                pass1.requestFocus();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: all Android SQLITE database tables "should" have a column named _id that auto increments _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT

Comment: @MD, hrskrs: `AUTOINCREMENT` is not required for autoincrement. The problem is something else

Comment: @BrianvanMaanen If you want the database to create an id for you, don't insert a value or insert a null value to the integer primary key column.

Comment: have you tried createng this table in an SQLITE client and then inserting rows? That way you can find a table definition that works... Then use this in your Android Application

Comment: @Hector Well thats ok if you have a filed `_id`, otherwise it is same doc that tells how to create an `AutoIncrement` field [here](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1)

Comment: @laalto so at  values.put(DBOpenHelper.getUserId(), count);
we should have no value or the null value if blank is no option, right?

so the whole "count" part is not needed.

Comment: That's right. You can remove the code that tries to count the rows, and remove the line of code that puts a value for userid in the contentvalues.

Comment: We posted the full code, I hope it will help all of you figure this out, even after the changed suggested my laalto we still only get "0" as the result